# Codemirror, how to add add-ons

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to add the `scroll past end` add-on for codemirror but I cannot add it to my codemirror instance.

I tried calling it like this `scrollPastEnd: true` in the options but that didn't work. I also tried using the `defineOption` function but the console says it is `undefined`.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 8):

First, you have to add the `scrollpastend.js` file (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/addon/scroll/scrollpastend.min.js) to your HTML document and not to the editor.

As the following code from `scrollpastend.js` file  says, the `scrollPastEnd` option is off by default:

```
CodeMirror.defineOption("scrollPastEnd", false, function(cm, val, old) {..});
```

Then It only remains to activate your add-on by setting new option like this:

```
editor.setOption("scrollPastEnd", true);
```

or adding `scrollPastEnd` option to the object option list:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
  mode: "html",
  lineNumbers: true,
  scrollPastEnd: true
});
```

Hoping to help you, I wish you a good day.